# show html element before sending ajax sync request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to show `<div>` on click by submit before sending $.ajax()

my html

```
<div id="waiting_div"></div>
```

css

```
#waiting_div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
}
```

js functions

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#waiting_div").hide();
});

function set_response_waiting() {
    jQuery("#waiting_div").show();
}
function del_response_waiting() {
    jQuery("#waiting_div").hide();
}
```

and main js

```
jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function(){
    set_response_waiting(); <-- showing div here

    var len = window.prices.length; //array with data for sending
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (window.prices[i].price >= 0) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {...... },
                async: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                ...
            }).fail(function () {
                ...
            }).always(function () { 
                ...
            });
        }
    }

    del_response_waiting(); <-- hiding div
});
```

But set_response_waiting() function doesn't show me my "#waiting_div" before sending.

I need to redraw or update the DOM tree before sending. But how?

This don't work too..

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'update_price',
                            'car_id': car_id,
                            'dep_city_id': window.prices[i].dep,
                            'arr_city_id': window.prices[i].arr,
                            'price': window.prices[i].price
                        }, 
                        beforeSend: set_response_waiting(),
                        async: false
                        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, Promise.

jQuery ajax is aync method. so your function show and immediately hide.

```
 jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function(){
        set_response_waiting(); <-- showing div here

        var len = window.prices.length; //array with data for sending
        var i = 0;
        var deferreds = [];

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (window.prices[i].price >= 0) {
                deferreds.push(
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        data: {...... },
                        async: false
                    }).done(
                        function (data) {
                           ...
                        }
                    ).fail(function () {
                            ...
                        }
                    ).always(function () { ...
                        });
                );
            }
        }
        // pending until all ajax requests done.
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
            del_response_waiting(); <-- hiding div
        });
  });
```

--- EDIT

```
 jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function(){
        set_response_waiting(); <-- showing div here

        var len = window.prices.length; //array with data for sending
        var i = 0;
        var deferreds = [];

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            deferreds.push(deferred.promise());

            if (window.prices[i].price >= 0) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {...... },
                    async: false
                }).done(
                    function (data) {
                       ...
                    }
                ).fail(function () {
                        ...
                    }
                ).always(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(); // Resolve here!
                        ...
                    });
                );
            }
        }
        // pending until all ajax requests done.
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
            del_response_waiting(); <-- hiding div
        });
  });
```

---- EDIT (last)

```
jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function(){
    var send_price = function() {
      var deferreds = [];

      var len = window.prices.length; //array with data for sending
      var i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (window.prices[i].price >= 0) {
              deferreds.push(
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                    data: { price : window.prices[i].price },
                    async: false
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log('done', data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.error(done, data);
                }).always(function () { 

                })
              );
          }
      }
      $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
          del_response_waiting();
      });

    }
    set_response_waiting();
    setTimeout(send_price); // setTimeout for browser redraw screen!!

});
```

Check jsfiddle for working example. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/yourimiyi/rsu4vo3m/

Comment: it work only with `async: true`, but with  `async: true` it worked and before. i need  `async: false`

Comment: okay, updated to use $.Deferred(), If not working please let me know. It should works whatever async or not. :)

Comment: Igor Korobko, Sorry about taking your time. I didn't test code. so I tested it fully and edit again. :) forgive me. BTW, $.when or use deferred is good choice for async job.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous as you are probably aware of, so in your function JS will go straight from set_response_waiting() to del_response_waiting(); AJAX is not performed 'in series here'; try:

```
jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function(){
        var len = window.prices.length; //array with data for sending
        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            if (window.prices[i].price >= 0) {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: {...... },
                    async: false
                }).done(
                    function (data) {
                      del_response_waiting(); //<-- hiding div
                       ...
                    }
                ).fail(function () {
                        ...
                    }
                ).always(set_response_waiting()); //<-- showing div here
            }
        }

  });
```

Comment: .always() will be executed after getting response. i need do it before sending. or no??

Comment: Did you try it before posting that comment? -I'm asking because .always() is the default state when the ajax call starts and it will jump to .done() when it's done (and there were no errors); then the first thing that the .done() event does is trigger del_response_waiting(). So, again, test it first please..

Comment: What do your set_response_waiting() and del_reponse_waiting() functions look like? I can almost guarantee the problem lies there since what I described in my prior comment is EXACTLY how the flow in AJAX calls go.

Comment: `function set_response_waiting() {
    jQuery("#waiting_div").show();
}
`

Comment: `
function del_response_waiting() {
    jQuery("#waiting_div").hide();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Like [rsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5824370/rsn) said in first answer it happens but you can't solve it this way.

Here I set 2sec timeouts so you can see how it happens (I changed your code a bit just for testing purpose):

```
jQuery("#save_changed_prices").click(function() {
  $('#waiting_div').show();

  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
    }).done(
      function(data) {
        $('#waiting_div').html('show after ajax submit');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#waiting_div').hide();
        }, 2000);
      }
    ).fail(function() {}).always(function() {});
  }, 2000);
});
```

You can check example of it here https://jsfiddle.net/1e4xscn8/2/

Comment: but how i can pass the data in to the function for send?